# EXTJS 4 me.dom is undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I always getting the following error, if i activate a tab in my tabpanel, with setActiveTab(2); Here the error:

me.dom is undefined
[Break On This Error] me.dom.style.width = me.addUnits(width);

The element which not have dom defined, is a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the same question when I was developing a Tab page (Ext.). I checked my code and finally I found that all the tab pages used the same id(properties).